# Typescript Error TS1003 when attempting to access object properties using bracket notation

Tags: typescript

What is the proper way to reference an object property using bracket notation in TypeScript?

In regular JavaScript, I can do this:

```
returnValue(object, key) {
  return object[key];
}
```

And if I call `returnValue({someKey: 1}, "someKey")`, the function returns `1`.

When I try to do this in TypeScript, I receive:

`TS1003: Identifier expected. Name expected.`

What's the proper way to do this?

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a [mcve]; if I [paste that code into an IDE](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/E4UwLgrsB2BqCGAbCIAUB7ARgKxAYzABoACAaxAE8BKAWACgBve4l40SGYrXAgbXIoBdANz0AvkA) I get a bunch of errors because it's not valid JS or TS by itself (it must be a method definition, but out of context), but not "identifier expected".  Please help us reproduce your issue and then someone can guide you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might consider using `keyof`:

```js
interface YourObj {
    someKey: string;
    someOtherKey: number;
}
function returnValue(obj: YourObj, key: keyof YourObj) {
    return obj[key];
}

console.log("Object value = " + returnValue({someKey: "someValue", someOtherKey: 1}, "someKey"))
```

This will give you compilation errors if you call `returnValue` on anything that isn't `YourObj` and any key that doesn't appear in `YourObj`

Answer (score 0):

Typescript is a strict superset of JavaScript, so JavaScript is legal in Typescript.

JavaScript object property accessors using the dot notation or the bracket notation are both valid in Typescript. Running the example code below does not generate any errors or warnings.

For more assistance, you will need to provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

See <kbd>[**TypeScript Playground Demo**](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?target=2#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAJwKZRMsA1AhgGxFQAo4AjAKwC5FcwBPAGkQGtV6aBnKZGMAcwCUiAN4AoRJJTpMSchQDabegF0A3GIC+YsRASc4+VADp8cfsQBEAeUqpoiAG4EiiALyJLiANTSMWPEISEQMAW1QAaXYaAEZNZkswyPZLQUEgA)</kbd>

```
function returnValue(obj: any, key: string) {
    return obj[key];
}

console.log("Object value = " + returnValue({someKey: 1}, "someKey"))
```

## Output

```
Object value = 1
```